# ScrollView with ConstraintLayout Guidelines do not work

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Guideline's with scrollview, however they are not appearing.
It work's perfectly fine without scrollview.

Without `ScrollView` `Guidelines` work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_80"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

With a `ScrollView` as the parent container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_80"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />
        

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

[image]

What's a solution for using Guidelines with scrollview?

I'm trying to create a cover picture for the user's profile using an ImageView:
based on a Guideline that is `0.2 percent` covering the top part of the layout.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline_20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_20"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView` to use Guidelines without setting a defined height.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline_20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />
```

Comment: that was not me who downvoted you by the way. I'm trying to make the ImageView the first view

Comment: I'm trying to completely avoid setting a defined ```dp``` number like 200. Using only Guidelines

Comment: but you need to add some views to otherwise constraint layout default height 0dp it need child then it show the guidenes in editor

Comment: Oh okay I figured it out. You need to add a ```android:fillViewport="true"``` to the ScrollView in order to use the guidelines without setting a defined height layout

Comment: can you change your answer to ```android:fillViewport="true"``` ill mark it correct